# Why does mysql process starts on boot?

Tags: server, boot, mysql, upstart, init

As you can see, mysql exists only in the `/etc/init.d` directory and not in `/etc/rcN.d`, therefore it shouldn't start on boot.

```
$ sudo find /etc -regex ".*\(rc.*d\|init\.d\).*" | sudo grep "mysql" | sort
/etc/init.d/mysql
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MySQL is started by upstart. You can find the configuration file at `/etc/init/mysql.conf`

Comment: Thanks. I've edit that file and replaced the line `   and runlevel [2345])` with `   and runlevel [345])`.

Comment: You can also be more clear and say 'start on never'

Comment: New versions of Ubuntu use upstart(http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to manage service (start/stop/restart etc).
It's a good system but I'm unable to disable a service to start on Ubuntu startup.
I think that edit the configuration file as advised by txwikinger isn't a good method, so how to proceed?

Comment: Unfortunately, currently this might be the only method. Maybe we need some better way to allow packaged configuration being mixed with local additions for upstart.